# How to change cordinates of path object

Tags: fabricjs

How to change cordinates of path object?

This is not working:

```
var line=new fabric.Path(' M10 10 L 50 50',{stroke:"black",strokeWidth: 2});

canvas.add(line);
line.path[1][0] = 100;
canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
```

Comment: What is not working? Please give us some details about your problem. You can not paste code and wait for people to find the problems and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function for it: `setCoords()`

For example:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var line=new fabric.Path(' M10 10 L 50 50',{stroke:"black",strokeWidth: 2});
canvas.add(line);
line.set({ left: 100, top: 100 }).setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6Y6k/16/

Comment: Thanks, but i am looging to change the first cordinate and the last, seperetly.
Like change the M 10 10 to M 40 40, and change the L 50 50 to L 150 150 ??
Can it be done ?

Comment: Just found it ! On some forum.
 line.path[0] = ["M", 100, 100];